# Проблема работы Ajax-запроса на сервере

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, django, ajax

Такая проблема, есть сайт на Django (интернет-магазин), из корзины можно удалить товар кнопкой remove_from_cart. Проблема следующая: эта кнопка отлично работает на локальном хосте, но на обычном хосте она вообще не работает и выдает `jquery-3.7.1.min.js:2     POST http://thewoman.balayi3c.beget.tech/remove-from-cart/31/%D0%A7%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9/ 400 (Bad Request)`

```js
 $(document).ready(function() {
      // Обработка удаления товара из корзины
      $('.remove-item').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var productId = $(this).attr('data-product-id');
        var color = $(this).attr('data-color');
        console.log(productId, color)
        removeCartItem(productId, color);
      });
      function removeCartItem(productId, color) {
        var csrf_token = "{{ csrf_token }}";
        var url = '{% url 'remove_from_cart' 0 0 %}'.replace('0', productId).replace('0', color);
        $.ajax({
          type: 'POST',
          url: url,
          data: {
            csrfmiddlewaretoken: '{{ csrf_token }}'
          },
          success: function(response) {
            location.reload(); 
            console.log(url)
          },
          error: function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
            // Обработка ошибки
            console.log(xhr.responseText);
            console.log(url)
          }
        });
      }
```

```html
<div class="tabel-row-item delete-but"><a href="{% url 'remove_from_cart' cart_item.product.id cart_item.color %}" class="remove-item" data-product-id="{{ cart_item.product.id }}" data-color="{{ cart_item.color }}" style="font-size: 20px;"><i class="fa-regular fa-circle-xmark" style="color: #ff0000;"></i></a></div>&nbsp;
```

```
views.py:

@csrf_exempt
def remove_from_cart(request, product_id, color):
    product_id = str(product_id)
    cart = request.session.get('cart', {})
    cart_item_key = f"{product_id}_{color}"
    print(product_id)
    print(color)
    if cart_item_key in cart:
        del cart[cart_item_key]
        request.session['cart'] = cart
        return redirect('cart')
    else:
        return HttpResponse(f'Item with product_id {product_id} and color {color} not found in the cart.', status=400)
```